# Dynamic array allocation of a record in Ada

Tags: free, ada, dynamic-arrays, new-operator

I am trying to dynamically allocate a large array in Ada (well, an array of an array).
For instance, I'm able to dynamically allocate an object like so:

```
type Object;
type ObjPtr is access Object;
OP : ObjPtr;
-- sometime later
OP := new Object;
OP.Index := I;--OP.Ptr.all;
Free(OP);
```

I'm trying to emulate this benchmark code:

```
Object **objList = new Object*[500000];
int32_t *iList = new int32_t[500000];
for (int32_t i = 0; i < 500000; ++i)
{
  objList[i] = new Object;
  iList[i] = Object::getIndex(objList[i]);
  delete objList[i];
}
delete[] iList;
delete[] objList;
```

Sadly, I'm unable to even do something like this c++ equivalent:

```
Object *objList = new Object*[500000];
```

I came up with this much so far:

```
type objs is array (Positive range <>) of Object;
type objList is access objs;
```

But I'm probably way off.

Comment: Where's the array of an array?

Comment: What "benchmark" are we talking about? Schedler shows one way to do it, but you really almost never need to actually do something like this in Ada (and really should avoid it in C++ too). Also, most likely Ada's `new` is implemented as a call to the exact same OS routine C++'s `new` uses. Thus benchmarking its dynamic allocation performance is both pointless and silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ada your C++ code would translate roughly to the following:

```
Alloc_Count : constant := 500_000;
type ObjPtr is access Object;
type ObjArray is array (1 .. Alloc_Count) of ObjPtr;
OA : ObjArray;
begin
   for I in OA'Range loop
   OA(I) := new Object;
   -- ... do the other things
end loop;
```

If you want to use dispatching operations with your objects (i.e. the `Object` is defined as a **tagged type**), use `Object'class` instead of `Object` in the `ObjPtr` declaration.